# sort nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I would like to sort Dictionary by value in nested Dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> Data = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>>();

Dictionary<string, string> oneRow = new Dictionary<string,string>();
oneRow.Add("id", "1");
oneRow.Add("name", "John");
oneRow.Add("surname", "Petrucci");
oneRow.Add("data", "2014-01-01");
oneRow.Add("active", "1");
this.Data[1] = oneRow;

oneRow = new Dictionary<string, string>();
oneRow.Add("id", "2");
oneRow.Add("name", "Joe");
oneRow.Add("surname", "Satriani");
oneRow.Add("data", "2014-02-02");
oneRow.Add("active", "1");
this.Data[2] = oneRow;

oneRow = new Dictionary<string, string>();
oneRow.Add("id", "3");
oneRow.Add("name", "Steve");
oneRow.Add("surname", "Vai");
oneRow.Add("data", "2014-03-03");
oneRow.Add("active", "0");
this.Data[3] = oneRow;
```

How can I sort this.Data by 'name' or for example by 'surname' DESC ?

I was searching but I have not found solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the shortest way:

```
Data = Data.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value["name"])
           .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Data = Data.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value["name"]);    it is possible ?

Comment: @mtoy A Dictionary does not keep any order between the elements, so even if you could, you'd lose the ordering you just did.